# How to find a range from two columns in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a value say 45.

I want to check whether this value is present in database or not.

The problem is that I have two columns, say:

```
--------------------
range_from  range_to
--------------------
   10 ------------ 20
--------------------
   21 ------------ 30
--------------------
   31 ------------ 40
--------------------
   41 ------------ 50
--------------------
```

How can I find this value?

```
SELECT * FROM Score WHERE range_from='' AND range_to=''
```

Answer (score 9):

Normally you would use the keyword 'BETWEEN'

```
SELECT * FROM score 
WHERE 45 BETWEEN range_from AND range_to
```

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT *
FROM score
WHERE range_from < 45 AND range_to > 45;
```

Answer (score 2):

To take care of boundary conditions also we can consider small correction in the above answer

```
SELECT *
FROM score
WHERE range_from <= 50 AND range_to >= 50;
```